# How to Convert Java Object to XML object with java keyword

Tags: java, xml, serialization

I create an java class:

```
public class ReturnObj {

    private String returncode;
    private String returndesc;
    private Pkg pkg;
    public String getReturncode() {
        return returncode;
    }

    public void setReturncode(String returncode) {
        this.returncode = returncode;
    }

    public String getReturndesc() {
        return returndesc;
    }

    public void setReturndesc(String returndesc) {
        this.returndesc = returndesc;
    }

}
```

and other class:

```
public class Pkg {

    private String packagecode;
    private String cycle;
    private String price;
    private String desc;
    public String getPackagecode() {
        return packagecode;
    }

    public void setPackagecode(String packagecode) {
        this.packagecode = packagecode;
    }

    public String getCycle() {
        return cycle;
    }

    public void setCycle(String cycle) {
        this.cycle = cycle;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}
```

And I Want to convert object ReturnObj to this XML

```html
<return>
    <returncode>1</returncode>
    <returndesc>DANG_KY_THANH_CONG</returndesc>
    <package>
        <packagecode>BD30</packagecode>
        <cycle>1</cycle>
        <price>15000</price>
        <desc> BD30</desc>
    </package>
</return>
```

So how do I serialize an attribute pkg to package in XML? Because Java doesn't allow to name variable as an keyword anh package is an keyword in Java !

Comment: What do you use to generate your XML? There are dozens of tools to do that. We don't know which one you chose.

Comment: There is no keyword that will allow you to convert a Java object to XML. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: it is clear what OP is asking by the examples he/she have given. OP wants an output with xml element name "package" which is a keyword in Java and thus is not allowed as variable name

Comment: @sharonbn The only thing that is clear is that the OP is asking for a solution based on a non-existent Java keyword.

Comment: @EJP, if my comment didn't clear it up, I don't see what more can I do. However, "package" is indeed a Java keyword and is indeed not allowed as variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JAXB marshling` in your class it will convert the object to XML, here is link to help you [JAXB Marshling](http://www.javatpoint.com/jaxb-marshalling-example)

Comment: that does not give an answer. the question was not how to convert object to XML

Comment: @sharonbn That is a fine solution (JAXB with annotations), when in the annotation explicitly state the name like `@XmlElement("package")`,

Comment: so perhaps the answer needs to include that bit of information

Comment: @sharonbn Do you realy think, we should write complete code and give complete solution for problem or any given drection for the problem so the the person who is having problem look in that direction and solve it by her/him self?

Comment: @HimanshuMishra, Yes, we should write complete code or at least give a complete answer to a specific question. This is the intention of this site. SO is not the place for school/training.  Anyway, Your answer can qualify for **all** questions related to XML marshaling. It is surely too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB API that comes with java for converting java object to XML.

Below is the code that will solve your requirement.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "return")
public class ReturnObj {

    private String returncode;
    private String returndesc;
    private Pkg pkg;

    public Pkg getPkg() {
        return pkg;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "package")
    public void setPkg(Pkg pkg) {
        this.pkg = pkg;
    }

    public String getReturncode() {
        return returncode;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "returncode")
    public void setReturncode(String returncode) {
        this.returncode = returncode;
    }

    public String getReturndesc() {
        return returndesc;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "returndesc")
    public void setReturndesc(String returndesc) {
        this.returndesc = returndesc;
    }

}
   @XmlRootElement
public class Pkg {
    private String packagecode;
    private String cycle;
    private String price;
    private String desc;

    public String getPackagecode() {
        return packagecode;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="packagecode")
    public void setPackagecode(String packagecode) {
        this.packagecode = packagecode;
    }

    public String getCycle() {
        return cycle;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="cycle")
    public void setCycle(String cycle) {
        this.cycle = cycle;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="price")
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}    

    import java.io.File;

    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
    import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

    public class JAXBExample {

        private static final String FILE_NAME = "C:\\ru\\jaxb-returnObj.xml";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ReturnObj returnObj = new ReturnObj();
            returnObj.setReturncode("1");
            returnObj.setReturndesc("DANG_KY_THANH_CONG");
            Pkg pkg = new Pkg();
            pkg.setCycle("1");
            pkg.setPrice("15000");
            pkg.setDesc("BD30");
            returnObj.setPkg(pkg);
            jaxbObjectToXML(returnObj);
        }

        private static void jaxbObjectToXML(ReturnObj emp) {

            try {
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ReturnObj.class);
                Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
                // for pretty-print XML in JAXB
                m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

                // Write to System.out, this will print the xml on console
                m.marshal(emp, System.out);

                // Write to File
                m.marshal(emp, new File(FILE_NAME));
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

**Explanation:**

@XmlRootElement: This is a must have annotation for the Object to be used in JAXB. It defines the root element for the XML content.

@XmlElement: This will create the element. If you want to give some other name to the xml element when converting java object to xml then you can pass name attribute to the @XmlElement  Example:

```
@XmlElement(name = "package")
```

Execute above code to see the desired output.

Happy Coding.

Comment: and how does pkg variable gets serialized into "package" xml element? perhaps your example can include this crucial bit of information that was specifically requested?

Comment: If you want to serialize  pkg variable into  "package" xml element, then provide name = "package" in XmlElement annotation present on setPkg method of ReturnObj class. With name atrribute provided in the XmlElement, you can rename the java variable to some other name and then that name will be used in XML.  I have edited the above code. It will generate the exact XML you are looking for. Also have add output for the  above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try [xstream](http://x-stream.github.io/)

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("package", Pkg.class);
String xml = xstream.toXML(myReturnObj);
```